# How to make view controllers go to random view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the moment i have 9 game levels. After you complete the first game you go to results screen. After you press continue the results screen goes to second game and this continues until last game. I wanted to know if there is a way to make it so that after you press continue in the results screens it will go to random game level(or view controller). Sorry if my terminology is bad but i just started coding with objective-c and not sure if what im asking is possible without having to make a lot of segues for each level(view controller).Now i have 20 view controllers in my story board. 1.Intro screen. 1.Name submitting screen. 9. game levels and 9 corresponding result screens.

Answer (score 2):

*Why don't you keep reference to your `viewControllers` in an `NSArray/NSSet` and once you want a random viewController select a random index with:*

```
arc4random();
```

Or if you don't want to init all the `viewControllers` at the start, you can create a set index to every `viewController`, and once the index is chosen you can init the matching `viewController`

Comment: Where would i implement it? in every game.m classes?

Comment: I would recommend implementing this somewhere that all of your viewControllers have access to

Comment: hmm Every game.h classes have imported Name.h would that be it?

Comment: Is game.h the place you init a random viewController?

Comment: i dont believe i init a random viewController anywhere since i dont even know how

Comment: Can you plz elaborate on how you change the viewControllers? Do you connect them all it interface builder or by code?

Comment: In interface builder. The code is not mine, im taken some1 elses code to play with and want to do some modifications, but im new to programming with ios

Comment: OK, then what are you using as adding you viewControllers? UITabViewController/UINavigationViewController?

Comment: Im not sure as the code was not made by me, Im just modifying. But I dont see any of these methods you specified.

Comment: So unless you don't show us your code or understand what is going on on it and explain it, i can't help you...